# Serving Static content from local hard disk in jboss as 7

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss5.x

I have deployed my application in jboss 4.2, it deployedd successfully.
To access static files on my hard disk i have included the following code in my server.xml(/server/default/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/server.xml)

```
<Host name="host_name">
    <Context path="/outputfiles" 
    docBase="/home/sample"
    reloadable="true">
    </Context>
</Host>
```

and its working fine, when i give the link http://:/outputfiles, the data in home/sample is accessible.

Now i m trying to migrate my application to jboss as 7.1. It has been deployed successfully. Now i m stucked up on where to add the specified part of code to access static content.

Pl. help me in this regard.

Is there any other way to access static content on hard disk using jboss as 7.1..

Thanks in advance.......

Answer (score 0):

As of my knowledge, we dont have an option to access static files on the hard disk through JBOSS AS 7.1.

The solution I have tried was , I have created a dummy web application and I have been storing the files into the dummy web application. Once the files are stored over there, they are accessed with URL pointing to newly created dummy web application.

Though this is not the correct way for this kind of access, I find no other way for this.

Pl. let me know if any other ideal way exists...

Thanks....